# NSMutableArray becomes empty?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have noticed, that even that my code is working great, something strange happen.

Assume I have two arrays: `passwordEntered` and `tempPasswordEntered`.

After I get a new `passwordEntered`,  I do this each time:

```
 tempPasswordEntered=[passwordEntered mutableCopy];
```

Then I clean :

```
 [passwordEntered  removeAllObjects];
```

then, next time I again do this (for the new `passwordEntered`):

```
 tempPasswordEntered=[passwordEntered mutableCopy];
```

So `tempPasswordEntered` has only the last `passwordEntered`, and not both of them.
if first time it had 4 places in array,the second time it still has 4 places, 
so my question is, does the copy REPLACE the array ? its not added to the last place of it as when you `addObject` ?

Another thing: should I use `retain` instead?

Comment: Post more code, better whole class, it's unclear and not enough info. Do you use ARC or retain/release, ...? How `passwordEntered` and `tempPasswordEntered` is defined, ...

Comment: Have tried : tempPasswordEntered=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: passwordEntered];

Comment: `mutableCopy` of `NSArray` does work in this way - it creates new array, which is mutable (even if origin `NSArray` wasn't mutable) and all objects inside the array are not copied -> shallow copy, not deep copy. All objects are retained in the new array as well. When you do release the origin array, all objects in the new mutable copy  are still alive and they do exist. When you do `tempPasswordEntered = [passwordEntered mutableCopy]` it assigns new array to the `tempPasswordEntered` and previous array in this ivar is trashed if you do use ARC. Provide more info ...

Comment: @VXtreme `[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array]` does the same thing as `[array mutableCopy]`. No need to try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSArray *retVal = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:fetchResults];
NSArray *retVal = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[fetchResults copy]];
NSArray *retVal = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[fetchResults retain]];
```

The latter two are simple leaks. The first is one way of making a copy, but retVal = [fetchResults copy]; is a better way to make a copy.

But, of course, you don't need a copy at all. That isn't the problem. You go on to say that the only thing that doesn't crash is an empty result set.

That indicates one of two things; either your result set is corrupt (unlikely) or you are accessing the result set incorrectly (likely).

Answer (score 1):

The line `tempPasswordEntered=[passwordEntered mutableCopy];` is a variable assignment, and like other assignments it changes the value of the variable completely. In this case, `tempPasswordEntered` now points to a copy of `passwordEntered`, which has only a single object in it. So yes, it does replace the array, like any other assignment would.

If you wanted to add the objects in `passwordEntered` to `tempPasswordEntered`, try `[tempPasswordEntered addObjectsFromArray:passwordEntered]`.

It sounds like what you want is `mutableCopy`, not `retain`, but I don't really know what your requirements are exactly so I can't say much more. You should probably be using ARC anyways :)